# DefaultMessageListenerContainer, get sessionTransacted-property working?

Tags: java, transactions, jms, spring-transactions, spring-jms

How's the proceeding, to let the DefaultMessageListenerContainer control transactions...as far as I read, I only have to provide the sessionTransacted-property to the DMLC. My goal is to put the message back to the queue, if some errors occure...

Has been searching for quite a while and but didn't found anything...

**My Spring-config (a part of it):**

```
<bean id="abstractMessageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" abstract="true">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="5"/>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="10000" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" parent="abstractMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="destinationName" value="MY.QUEUE" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="myMessageListener" />
            <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="myMessageListener" class="my.package.structure.ListenerClass"></bean>
```

**My Listener Class:**

```
public class ListenerClass implements MessageListener {


    public void onMessage(Message msg) {


    }

}
```

is it simply by throwing an unchecked exception (like java.lang.IllegalStateException)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

message will rollback in case a unchecked exception will be thrown! checked exceptions can't be thrown, because they're not mentioned in the method-signature of the onMessage-method of MessageListener interface.

Answer (score -1):

You are right about your assumption about `sessionTransacted`, if set to true in case of any failure in the listener the message will be rolled back - which basically means that the message will be back in the queue to be retried. Typically there is a limit on the number of retries allowed by the broker, if it exceeds a threshold the message will end up in the DLQ (Dead letter queue).

Comment: due to the fact that onMessage(Mesage arg0) ain't allow throwing any checked exceptions i gotta throw a UncheckedException, right?

Comment: Any exception should roll back the transaction - unchecked or checked,  doubt if it is specific to runtime exception alone

Comment: checked exceptions has to be mentioned in the method-signature, or? otherwise he javac would fail.